Visual Studio Code error when trying to make a new .NET project
I'm trying to make a new .NET project in Visual Studio Code, but I keep getting this error:
Command '.NET: New Project...' resulted in an error
Unable to get dotnet information to initialize template engine host
How do I fix this? I think there might be something wrong with my .NET SDK installation. I tried installing it from VSC, but it kept giving an undefined error. So, I downloaded the installer from the Microsoft website and used that, and it didn't give any errors. When I go to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk, it has the 8.0.301 folder, and it has stuff in it. However, when I run dotnet --list-sdks in the command prompt, it just shows an empty list. Not an error, just literally:
C:\Users\MyUsername>dotnet --list-sdks

C:\Users\MyUsername>

Could there be some environmental variable that isn't set?

Does it make any difference if you run the console as admin and fire the dotnet --list-sdks command again?

Nope. It's still empty.

Anything in dotnet --info ? Also, in PowerShell, check Get-Command dotnet and see whether it points to somewhere weird.

Here's what dotnet --info got: https://pastebin.com/5efKZrLD
As you can see, it says there are no SDKs installed...
The Get-Command says it's application dotnet.exe, version 7.0.923, source "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe". Should I change this to "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"?

Try the following: .NET SDK Download. Under SDK 8.0.301 heading, in the Windows row, uder the Installers column, click the desired version (ex: x64).

That's exactly how I installed it already. Unless you mean to download the binaries and do something with them?

I just installed it, and it works for me. Go to Control Panel => Programs and Features  and uninstall the existing version. Then re-install it. Ensure that you install it as an Administrator.

I reinstalled it in administrator mode and restarted my computer as well, but it still doesn't work. Everything is doing the same thing, except dotnet --list-sdks isn't even returning a blank line anymore.

I was able to fix it by modifying a Windows environment variable.

Go to 'System Properties'
Click the 'Environment Variables...' button
Under 'System variables', double click the 'Path' variable.
Using the 'Move Up', button, move 'C:\Program Files\dotnet' above 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet'
Click 'Ok' on all windows opened.


This is not a great fix... it's more of a hack. You should consider reporting your scenario to Microsoft so they can investigate.
